# MS Access 2007 text box values validate

Tags: ms-access, textbox, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an access form in which i enter some values...here once i enter n goto next textbox i want to check if the quantity entered in the text box is less than a value from a field in some table. i saw the option validation rule but dont knw how to check with a table value...thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to check against a table is DLookUp:

```
If Me.txtText = _
   DLookUp("Field_OrExpression","SomeTable","Optional_Where_Statement") Then
```

Note that DLookup returns Null if the data is not found.

-- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208786

Comment: where to do this operation..like in validation rule or on events like before update, after update, on exit...

Comment: It is not a validation rule, after that, it depends on the requirements of your application. For example, you may wish to use the form before update if you have several controls to validate. If the data must be corrected before the flow continues, you may wish to use before update for the control. If you wish to write information or change another control based on the information, you may wish to use after update for the control.